# getMeteorData race conditions with component lifecycle?

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm getting some pretty undesirable behavior in my app, and I'm having a hard time replicating the issue and/or figuring out what I'm doing wrong or not understanding about React that's causing my components to act this way.

What I want to do is to get some data from Mongo on the App component, then have all of that data readily available for any child that I want.

```
<App> //get data here, pass to children through props
    <ChildElement1 data={this.data.appData}/>
    <ChildElement2 data={this.data.appData}/>
    <ChildElement3 data={this.data.appData}/>
</App>
```

Here's how I've attempted to tackle this with React so far:

```
App = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

    getMeteorData() {
        let _id = 'exampleId';
        return {
            appData: Collection.findOne({_id})
        };
    },

    render() {
        return (<ChildElement1 data={this.data.appData} />);
    }
});

ChildElement1 = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            values: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'] //default values
        };
    },

    componentWillMount() {
        if(this.props.data.specificValues) {
            this.setState({values: this.props.data.specificValues});
        }
    },

    render() {
        let values = this.state.values;
        return (<span>{values[0]} {values[1]} {values[2]} {values[3]}</span>);
    }
});
```

So here's where it gets weird. When I call `componentWillMount()`, sometimes `this.props.data` is defined and other times it's not, which leads me to believe there's some sort of race conditions going on where sometimes that data gets loaded correctly as a prop and other times it doesn't.

I then figured that, well okay, I can't depend on the data prop being there before the component is initially mounted, so I could instead use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` and check the updated props that way (and update the state, if necessary). HOWEVER! After using `componentWillReceiveProps`, now `this.props.data` is seemingly ALWAYS correctly attached to the props of `ChildElement1` (which means `componentWillReceiveProps` doesn't run!).

My final solution was to use BOTH `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` to account for both situations and to do the exact same check in both locations. This fix works, but boy does it seem messy and probably indicates a lack of understanding of component lifecycles, how the meteor/react should properly interact, both, or something else completely.

I'd sure appreciate a bit of help here.

edit: I've come up with a small improvement - instead of using `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` to do the check to see if there are specific values defined in the Mongo Collection, I put that logic in `render` like so:

```
render() {
    let data = this.props.data,
        values = (data) ? data.specificValues : this.state.values;

    return (<span>{values[0]} {values[1]} {values[2]} {values[3]}</span>);
}
```

There's definitely still some sort of underlying issue, however, as I still don't understand why `this.props` is so inconsistent when given data retrieved from `getMeteorData`. This version is a bit more succinct, however.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better approach to this rather than passing the data returned from `getMeteorData` to each of the children as props. Using the methods described here: https://www.tildedave.com/2014/11/15/introduction-to-contexts-in-react-js.html, I explicitly listed the `childContextTypes` and `getChildContext` in `<App />` and then `contextTypes` in `<ChildElement1 />`, which allows `this.data.appData` to be available by way of `this.context` in `<ChildElement1 />` and presumably within any other children of `<App />`. Although I gotta admit, declaring every single proptype of the collection is a major PITA, seems like it'd be necessary to write a mixin (or rather, a bunch of mixins) to handle that stuff.